# obejct gets turned to string after 3 identical inputs

Tags: python, class, while-loop

I'm working on a text-adventure as a school project in Python 3.6. The code should let you "look" in different directions, depending on where you come from. The program crashes when the input is the same three times in a row, and I have no clue why. Also, the direction I face does not change consistently. Most of the time it works, but in some cases it doesn't.

I hope I didn't confuse anyone, but I am from Germany so here are some translations:

raum=room

oben=up

unten=down

I've tried putting a string input in between to break the chain.

```
class Place(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.infor = ''
        self.infol = ''
        self.infou = ''
        self.infod = ''
        self.ninfor = ''
        self.ninfol = ''
        self.ninfou = ''
        self.ninfod = ''   #n(ew)infod(own)
        self.up=''
        self.down=''
        self.right=''
        self.left=''
        self.nup=''
        self.ndown=''
        self.nright=''
        self.nleft=''
    def newDirection(self, room):
        room.nup = room.up          #n(ew)up
        room.ndown = room.down
        room.nright = room.right
        room.nleft = room.left
    def setDirection(self, room):
        room.up = room.nup          #n(ew)up
        room.down = room.ndown
        room.right = room.nright
        room.left = room.nleft
    def dup(self, room):
        room.nup = room.up
        room.ndown = room.down
        room.nright = room.right
        room.nleft = room.left
        room.ninfou = room.infou
        room.ninfod = room.infod
        room.ninfor = room.infor
        room.ninfol = room.infol
    def ddown(self, room):
        room.nup = room.down
        room.ndown = room.up
        room.nright = room.left
        room.nleft = room.right
        room.ninfou = room.infod
        room.ninfod = room.infou
        room.ninfor = room.infol
        room.ninfol = room.infor
    def dright(self):
        room.up = room.left
        room.down = room.right
        room.right = room.down
        room.left = room.up
    def dleft(self):
        room.up = room.right
        room.down = room.left
        room.right = room.up
        room.left = room.down

raum_1=Place()
raum_2=Place()
raum_3=Place()

raum_1.up = raum_2
raum_1.down = raum_1

raum_2.down = raum_1
raum_2.up = raum_3

raum_3.down = raum_2

raum_1.infou = "R1 Oben"

raum_2.infou = "R2 Oben"
raum_2.infod = "R2 Unten"

raum_3.infod = "R3 Unten"

position = raum_1
death = False
win = False

position.newDirection(position)

while(death != True)and(win != True):
    command=input()
    if command == 'up':
        position = position.nup
        position.dup(position)
    if command == 'down':
        position = position.ndown
        position.ddown(position)
    if command == 'right':
        position = position.nright
        position.dright
    if command == 'left':
        position = position.nleft
        position.dleft
    position.setDirection(position)
    print(position.ninfou, position.ninfod, position.ninfor, position.ninfol)
```

You should be able to switch rooms as many times as you want.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Informatik\Textadventure_game_2.py", line 90, in <module>
    position.ddown(position)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ddown'
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Comment: `position.dright` and `position.dleft` do absolutely nothing - you need parentheses to actually call the methods (although it's not clear why these two directions take no parameters, yet up & down do).

Comment: `raum_3` hasn't been assigned an `'up'` attribute, so it has the initial value - an empty string.  Either it needs to be a `Place` or you should add a check to prevent players selecting an invalid direction.

Answer (score 0):

For the bug when the directions you face change, look at dleft. You'll notice you can have set `room.up = room.right`, then `room.right = room.up`. This doesn't switch the two values--it simply sets `room.up` to `room.right`, and then `room.right` to `room.up`, which it already is.

```
def dright(self):
    room.up = room.left
    room.down = room.right
    room.right = room.down
    room.left = room.up
def dleft(self):
    room.up = room.right
    room.down = room.left
    room.right = room.up
    room.left = room.down
```

Python allows you to use **tuples** to shuffle values, so you don't have to say temp=a, a=b, b=temp, etc.

For dright:

```
(room.up,room.down,room.right,room.left) = (room.left,room.right,room,down,room.up)
```

For dleft:

```
(room.up,room.down,room.right,room.left) = (room.right,room.left,room.up,room.down)
```

Note: this is just transliterating your code. I think the following shifts everything left, while your code just flips pairs of directions:

```
(room.up,room.left,room.down,room.right) = (room.left,room.down,room.right,room.up)
```

And the following shifts right. I also like having the directions in clockwise or counterclockwise order.

```
(room.up,room.right,room.down,room.left) = (room.right,room.down,room.left,room.up)
```